# Making cursor move in the opposite direction of mouse movement input

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, cursor

So, I'm creating this webpage with a counter-intuitive way of navigating. What I'm hoping to achieve is to have to cursor move in the opposite direction of your mouse movement input.

What I did is hide the cursor altogether and let an element move in the opposite direction of mouse movement using JavaScript and CSS. The problem with this is I cannot get the new element to perform tasks like mouse enter and mouse hover.  Any ideas or suggestions as to what I could do with this?

Comment: You have to provide some code.

Comment: Can you try $("your element").mouseenter ?.Please share your codes for further help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get creative here. You could, for instance, add a handler to the window for onclick, onmousemove, etc..Inside that handler, use document.elementFromPoint(x, y) to get an element at a position and then explicitly fire events on that.

If you have overlapping elements (and want to trigger multiple events), you'll have to keep track internally of all elements that are 'interactable'. Perhaps by attaching a specific class or tag to them and then getting a list with a selector.